# Making a Python3 Variable Using a Counter

Tags: bash, python-3.x

I have some BASH code that I want to convert to Python3.

```
INPUTINDEX$INPUTCOUNTER="$INPUT"
```

Every time a user types an input the counter (code not shown) increases one number. With this code, the user's second input would be in variable INPUTINDEX2. INPUT, of course, is the user's input. The INPUTCOUNTER is a counter that increases each time an input is entered.

The question: How can I do this in Python3.3?

Comment: In isolation, that's not even valid `bash` code.

Comment: @chepner, your comment interests me. Could you explain why the code is not valid BASH code?

Comment: You cannot create dynamic variable names like that. `INPUTCOUNTER=3;INPUT=foo;INPUTINDEX$INPUTCOUNTER="$INPUT"` results in `bash: INPUTINDEX3=foo: command not found`. I said "in isolation" because you can play tricks with `eval` and `declare` to make it work, but as is, it results in an error.

Comment: @chepner, your results are interesting. In scripts, I have successfully used my BASH command.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest just appending to a list and the number of entries in the list is your counter.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

def main():
    entries=[]
    while True:
        entries.append(raw_input('input something: '))
        if not len(entries[-1]):
            entries=entries[:-1]
            break
    counter=len(entries)
    print 'counter %d, entries %s.' % (counter, entries)

if (__name__ == "__main__"):
    main()
```

Comment: I love your idea. Using a list would be more efficient. Plus, I am starting to think that I cannot do what I am trying to do in Python3 code. Thank you.